# named_scope for date.today Rails 2.3.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, named-scope

Working with a Rails 2.3.9 app and wondering how to write my named_scope such that I only get `workouts` from the current date. I am setting the timezone in in the application controller with a before_filter. The below doesn't throw an error, just doesn't filter:

workout.rb

```
named_scope :today_only, :conditions => [ "workouts.created_at <= ? AND workouts.created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now, 1.days.ago ]
```

application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :set_user_time_zone
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass your named scope variables?

Comment: Try to use lambda block in your named_scope. It might be the problem of caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not seeing the responses you want because Ruby is evaluating your call to Time.now when it evaluates your class definition, not when you're calling the scope. You need to pass a `lambda` to your `named_scope` call to get it to evaluate on every request:

```
# ensure that Time.now is evaluated on every call
named_scope :today_only, lambda {{ :conditions => ["workouts.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.at_beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day ] }}
```

Also, I think your Time boundaries may be incorrect. Are you looking for `workouts` that were created in the past 24 hours (relative to Time.now), or only workouts that were created "today?" Your example works for the former, the example above does the latter.

Comment: That all makes sense and it is the later that I want. But...I am getting this error when I put it in: `undefined method 'at_start_of_day' for Fri Apr 22 08:52:58 UTC 2011:Time`

Comment: ACK! Sorry, the method is actually `at_beginning_of_day'